# XHR redirect issue

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, xmlhttprequest

Imagine I have three domains A, B, and C. On both B and C I have made sure that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is sent when making a request.

Now on domain A I run an XHR like this:

```
xhr.open("GET", "B/abc.wav")
xhr.send()
```

B will make a redirect to C.

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Location: http://C/something/abc.wav
Content-Length: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

C will reply with

```
Content-Type: audio/wav
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=65
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1003914
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The issue I have is that in Chrome 14.0.835.126 beta-m I get an error as a result without giving me any hint of why this fails.

I only see "[Exception: DOMException]" as the response of the XHR.
Most examples on the web suggest to add the ACAO header which I have done but none actually talks about the scenario of multiple redirects. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: I created a proxy to get rid of the redirect. Did not test this ever again.

Comment: I've had the same problem. With a cross-origin XHR, Chrome cancels it when the server responds with a 302, 303, or 307.